# Python. Modifying values in a dictionary of unknown depth

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's assume I have a list that looks like this, but may vary in depth and complexity:

```
inc = {'root': 10, 
    'values': {
         'left': {8: {
             'left': {
                 6: {
                    'left': 5, 
                    'right': 11}
                  }, 
             'right': {
                  10: {
                     'left': 2, 
                     'right': 11}
               }}}, 
         'right' : {
                  12: {
                     'left': 5, 
                     'right': 20}
                  }}}
```

What I need to do is traverse it, find the lowest left value and the leftmost value (that is, a value that is reached by accessing 'left' elements of the dictionary) and swap them. Recursively traversing a dictionary to find the values is not an issue. The problem is locating the necessary values after I've determined what needs to be changed.

Function used for iteration:

```
leftmost = 0
lowest = 0

def walk_dict(d):
    global leftmost, lowest

    for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            walk_dict(v)
        else:
            if k == 'left':
                if leftmost == 0:
                    leftmost = v
                if v < lowest:
                    lowest = v
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a strange way to store a binary tree in dictionaries. It feel much more natural to me to use nested lists, or do something like `{'value': 5, 'left': {'value': 4}, 'right': {'value': 7, 'left': {'value': 12}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping values directly, keep the dictionaries holding them, so you can swap the values at the end, for example:

```
[in the loop]
  if k == 'left':
    if not leftmost:
      leftmost = d
    if v < lowest['left']:
      lowest = d

# swap
lefmost['left'], lowest['left'] = lowest['left'], lefmost['left']
```

Also I'm not sure about your definition of *leftmost*, but if it means the least deep key that equals to "left", your code is wrong as it simply grabs the first value found during the depth-first traversal. To overcome the problem you could keep the current depth and compare it as well to determine if the leftmost value should be overwritten.

Comment: Leftmost is the deepest key, that cam be reached by only walking left. So the code is correct. Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Comment: ah, all right, it'll be good then! I've been thinking about the tree growing from the left to the right as it was expressed by python dictionary in the code :)